# How to add filenames to file and search for them in powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have this script that I need to basically get all the .pdf files in a folder and then in that moment it needs to check if any of those file names are in a txt file containing filenames and if it is it will do some set of steps, same as if it is not. I have only made it so far as im not very fluent with powershell.Below is what i got if anyone can help me out! Thanks!

```
$dir = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\*.pdf"
$names = "C:\Users\user\Downloads\content.txt"

#check for .pdf files in folder
If (Test-Path -Path $dir )
{
    $files = Get-ChildItem $dir
    foreach($file in $files)
        {
        # Steps to search for filename within $names file that contains list of files
        # Steps if file found
            {
                #do these steps
            }
            else
            {
                #do these steps instead and then add all the filenames to $names file
                Add-Content $names $file.Name

            }
              
        }
 
}
Else 
{
Write-Host "N/A"
Exit
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) for this:

```
$inNames = Select-String -Path "$names" -Pattern ('^' + "$file" + '$') -CaseSensitive -List
```

This returns the first line in `"$names"` file consisting solely of `"$file"`, case-sensitive.

You probably also want to load the content file inside of a string so that the command doesn't have to open it every time it runs.
For that use:

```
$namesContent = Get-Content -Path "$names"
$inNames = $namesContent | Select-String -Pattern ('^' + "$file" + '$') -CaseSensitive -List
```

Answer (score 0):

To rephrase wat you're asking for...

1. Search for all PDFs in `"C:\Users\user\Downloads\"`.
2. Compare to the names found in `"C:\Users\user\Downloads\content.txt"`.

   - If they're already in the list, do "other stuff".
   - If not, add the names to `"C:\Users\user\Downloads\content.txt"`?

Presuming my assumptions are correct, you can use the following:

```
$fileNames = Get-Content -Path ($path = 'C:\Users\user\Downloads\content.txt') 
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -Path ($path | Split-Path) -Filter '*.pdf' -File))
{
    if ($file.BaseName -in $fileNames) {
        Write-Verbose -Message ("File name ['{0}'] already in list" -f $file.Name) -Verbose

        #The rest of the code here for the current iteration of the file found in 'content.txt'.

    }
    else {
        Write-Verbose -Message ("Adding ['{0}'] to '{1}'" -f $file.Name,$path) -Verbose
        Add-Content -Path $path -Value $file.BaseName -WhatIf
    }
}
```

In the first `if` statement, the file(s) are checked to see if they are already in the list. If the file names are already in the list, display a message saying so - then, in the same `if` body, you can add the rest of the code for the files that were found.

In the `else` statement, the file(s) not found will have the name added to the list.

---

*Remove the `-WhatIf` common/safety parameter from `Add-Content` once you've dictated that is the appropriate action you want it to take, for the files that weren't found*.

Comment: this worked, i appreciate the help! New to using powershell so this was helpful!